# byref parameter, not allowed to change method

Tags: dialog, screenshot, capture, byref

i've got an very old method:

```
dim out as Integer = 0
DontTouchClass.Foo(out)
'byref parameter
DoMore()
```

The "DontTouchClass" Methode shows a Dialog and the "out" Parameter is the "returncode". 
The problem is: **The Dialog fades away too slowly before a screenshot is taken.**
My ugly solution

```
Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
```

I am not allowed to change the method Foo.
What' a better solution for this problem?

Comment: Looks like VB.NET, but I think you need to provide more information and actual code to get some real help

Comment: thats all: DoMore() makes the screenshot with the Dialog still visible.

Comment: I use .net 4.6 and MsgBox and
this strange thing:
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Collections.Specialized
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6
Namespace UnsafeNative
   <System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
   Public Module user32
      Declare Function APISetFocus Lib "user32" Alias "SetFocus" (ByVal hwnd As Integer) As Integer